# Where to put Elastic Beanstalk config commands that are only run once on spin-up?

Tags: configuration, amazon-web-services, provisioning, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I know I can put commands in my source code in .ebextensions/*.config using the `commands` array. These are executed on *every* deploy however.  What about if I want to execute a configuration command only once when spinning up a new instance?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Commands can be run conditionally using the `test:` modifier. You specify a test to be done. If the test returns 0, the command is run, otherwise it is not.

If the last command in your config file touches a file, and the commands above that you only want to run once check for the existence of that file, then those commands will only run the first time.

```
commands:
  01-do-always:
    command: run_my_script
  02-do-on-boot:
    command: script_to_run_once
    test: test ! -f .semaphore
  99-signal-startup-complete:
    command: touch .semaphore
```

On Windows it would be something like this

```
commands:
  01-do-always:
    command: run_my_script
  02-do-on-boot:
    command: script_to_run_once
    test: if exists c:\\path\\to\\semaphore.txt (exit 0) else (exit 1)
  99-signal-startup-complete:
    command: date > c:\\path\\to\\semaphore.txt
```

Comment: How would you do the same thing but on a windows server? How does the syntax differ? Thanks.

Comment: Updated the post with a Windows example.

Comment: So I guess this applies to the `commands` section, whereas for `container_commands` you could use the `leader-only` option instead? Or did I misinterpret the question?

Comment: @djvg `leader-only` only executes the command on 1 instance within a target group. The question here is about executing a command on every instance but only once.

Comment: `.semaphore` didn't work for me, I think the current directly is the temporary deployment directory which is erased on every deployment. It worked with a different directory, I decided to use `/var/elasticbeanstalk/...`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows this should work:

```
commands:
  01-do-always:
    command: run_my_script
  02-do-on-boot:
    command: script_to_run_once
    test: cmd /c "if exist c:\\semaphore.txt (exit 1) else (exit 0)"
  99-signal-startup-complete:
    command: echo %date% %time% > c:\\semaphore.txt
```

Note that I had to change the `test` command from Jim Flanagan's answer.