# Beanstalk on Windows: How do I prevent commands running on re-deployment?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to take advantage of AWS Elastic Beanstalk's facility to customize the EC2 instances it creates. This requires creating a [.config file in the .ebextensions directory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html).

You can specify a number of commands which should be executed when the application is deployed to an instance. I'm using that to install some msi files, and also to configure EC2 to assign the instance a unique name. This then requires a reboot.

My problem is that I only want these commands to be run when an instance is first deployed. When I deploy a code-only change to existing instances they shouldn't be run.

I've tried using the "test" parameter, which should prevent the command running. I create a file as the last command, and then I check for the presence of that file in the "test" parameter. But it doesn't seem to work.

My config file is like this:

```
# File structure documented at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html
files:
  "C:\\Users\\Public\\EnableEc2SetComputerName.ps1":
    source: "[File Source]"
commands:
  init-01-ec2setcomputername-enable:
    test: cmd /c "if exist C:\\Users\\Public\\initialised (exit 1) else (exit 0)"
    command: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\\Users\\Public\\EnableEc2SetComputerName.ps1"
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
  init-05-reboot-instance:
    test: cmd /c "if exist C:\\Users\\Public\\initialised (exit 1) else (exit 0)"
    command: shutdown -r # restart to enable EC2 to set the computer name
    waitAfterCompletion: forever
  init-06-mark-initialised:
    test: cmd /c "if exist C:\\Users\\Public\\initialised (exit 1) else (exit 0)"
    command: echo initialised > C:\\Users\\Public\\initialised
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
```

Is there an alternative way to accomplish this? Or am I doing something stupid?

On Unix-based systems, there are the `touch` and `test` commands (referred to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16846429/1727) asking the equivalent question for Unix systems). What's the equivalent in Windows which will work best in this situation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to put Elastic Beanstalk config commands that are only run once on spin-up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827417/where-to-put-elastic-beanstalk-config-commands-that-are-only-run-once-on-spin-up)

Comment: @JimFlanagan thanks for that, but your answer seems to be Unix-specific: I tried the approach you outlined, and it fails on Windows. I've updated my question to emphasise that this is Windows-specific.

Comment: I like the (cmd /c "if exist) trick very useful, used my deploy scripts as well

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem lies in the fact that you are rebooting the machine before you can write the initialized file. You should be able use a bat file which first writes the semaphore, then reboots the instance, and run that .bat file contingently on the existence of semaphore.

You can either download the .bat file with a `files:source:` directive or compose it in the .config with a `files:content:` directive.

Otherwise, your `test:` lines look good (I tested them locally, without a reboot).

Comment: Actually - I think this is a better answer than mine.  Looking more closely - if you add a waitAfterCompletion, you can ensure that it's finished before rebooting - which may be able to avoid the batch file and not change your script too much.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, no.  Elastic Beanstalk is an abstraction and looks after the underlying infrastructure for you.  You give up a lot of environment control and gain easier deployment.  If you research into CloudFormation - in particular the meta-data and cfn-init / cfn-hup, you'll see a very similar construct around the beanstalk `files` and `commands` 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html

If you need to do instance customization beyond application customization - then you're possibly using the wrong tool, and having to put clumsy workarounds (until touch/test arrive from AWS)  Cloud Formation scripts would probably be a better fit.

I wrote about how to [configure windows instances via cloudformation](http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/08/05/bootstrapping-on-aws/) and there's also [extensive documentation on Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) itself.

Given you've done all the hard work around the commands, I think it would be pretty easy to shift to a Cloud Formation script, and plonk the one time startup code into userdata.

**edit - I think you could do it like this though if you went with elastic beanstalk
`command: dir initialised || powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\\Users\\Public\\EnableEc2SetComputerName.ps1"`

Comment: from what I can tell Amazon are moving in the direction of making more of the Cloud Formation features available to Beanstalk to provide just this kind of customisation

Comment: sorry for being slow, but could you explain what the "dir initialised || powershell.exe ..." syntax is supposed to do?

Comment: dir initialised searches for the file "initialised".  If it doesn't find it, then it executes the powershell.exe script.  (You can use && instead of || if it does find it)

Comment: A bit more info http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a very similiar problem, and utilized the answer from Jim Flanagan above and created a PowerShell script to do this.

```
#  restarts the server if this is not the first deployment
 param (

 )


$strFileName="C:\Users\Public\fwinitialised.txt"
If (Test-Path $strFileName){
  #This file was created on a previous deployment, reboot now.
  Restart-Computer -Force
}Else{
  # this is a new instance, no need to reboot.
  New-Item $strFileName -type file 
}
```

And in the .ebextensions file...

```
6-reboot-instance:
    command: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\\PERQ\\Deployment\\RestartServerOnRedeployment.ps1" 
    waitAfterCompletion: forever
```