# Why am I getting 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 - Rails App on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to Run Rails App on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and although I was able to deploy the app successfully with green healthy instance and connect to created RDS. When I click the production link I am getting 502 Bad Gateway - nginx/1.18.0
I am scratching my head over this for some time now.
I am running Rails 6.0.3.5 with Puma Version 4.3.7 (ruby 2.6.6-p146)
Here's my production.rb :

```
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on Tiago's advice.
  #config.consider_all_requests_local = true


  
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress CSS using a preprocessor.
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  # config.assets.compile = false

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain.
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment).
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "quickroll_production"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  # Inserts middleware to perform automatic connection switching.
  # The `database_selector` hash is used to pass options to the DatabaseSelector
  # middleware. The `delay` is used to determine how long to wait after a write
  # to send a subsequent read to the primary.
  #
  # The `database_resolver` class is used by the middleware to determine which
  # database is appropriate to use based on the time delay.
  #
  # The `database_resolver_context` class is used by the middleware to set
  # timestamps for the last write to the primary. The resolver uses the context
  # class timestamps to determine how long to wait before reading from the
  # replica.

  config.force_ssl = false
  #
  # By default Rails will store a last write timestamp in the session. The
  # DatabaseSelector middleware is designed as such you can define your own
  # strategy for connection switching and pass that into the middleware through
  # these configuration options.
  # config.active_record.database_selector = { delay: 2.seconds }
  # config.active_record.database_resolver = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
  # config.active_record.database_resolver_context = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session
end
```

And Puma.rb:

```
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
#
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }    

# Specifies the `pidfile` that Puma will use.
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }

bind "unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock"

pidfile "/var/run/puma/my_app.sock"   

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked web server processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
# preload_app!

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart

# bind "unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
# pidfile "/var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.2'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
# gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

gem 'font-awesome-sass'

#Devise Gem
gem 'devise'

#Pundit Gem
gem 'pundit'

gem "chartkick"

#Install figaro to manage local environment variables. Read more https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro
gem 'figaro'

#Install uickbooks ruby gem. Read more https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby
gem 'quickbooks-ruby'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'prawn'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'xero-ruby'
gem 'sassc', '~> 2.1.0'
```

I have also created two extension files to install the bundler and Gems and to setup Node and Yarn

here's my Packages.config

```
# Install git in order to be able to bundle gems from git
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    patch: []

commands:
  #01 && 02 needs for build native extension. See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=550901&#550053
  01_bundlerfix_command:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/.post-provisioning-complete
    command: gem install rubygems-update -v '<3'
    leader_only: false
  02_update_rubygems:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/.post-provisioning-complete
    command: $(which update_rubygems)
    leader_only: false
  # 03_bundlerfix_command:
  #   test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/.post-provisioning-complete
  #   command: gem install bundler -v 2.2.0
  #   leader_only: false
  # Run rake with bundle exec to be sure you get the right version
  add_bundle_exec:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre
    # 複数マッチ対応と上書き防止(後読み)
    command: perl -pi -e 's/((?<!bundle exec )rake)/bundle exec $1/g' 11_asset_compilation.sh 12_db_migration.sh
  # Bundle with --deployment as recommended by bundler docs
  #   cf. http://gembundler.com/v1.2/rationale.html under Deploying Your Application
  add_deployment_flag:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre
    # 複数マッチ対応と上書き防止(先読み)
    command: perl -pi -e 's/(bundle install(?! --deployment))/$1 --deployment/' 10_bundle_install.sh
  # Vendor gems to a persistent directory for speedy subsequent bundling
  make_vendor_bundle_dir:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
    command: mkdir -p /var/app/support/vendor_bundle
  # Store the location of vendored gems in a handy env var
  set_vendor_bundle_var:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support
    command: sed -i '12iexport EB_CONFIG_APP_VENDOR_BUNDLE=$EB_CONFIG_APP_SUPPORT/vendor_bundle' envvars
  # The --deployment flag tells bundler to install gems to vendor/bundle/, so
  # symlink that to the persistent directory
  symlink_vendor_bundle:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre
    command: sed -i 's/\(^cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_ONDECK\)/\1\nln -s $EB_CONFIG_APP_VENDOR_BUNDLE .\/vendor\/bundle/' 10_bundle_install.sh
  # Don't run the above commands again on this instance
  #   cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16846429/283398
  z_write_post_provisioning_complete_file:
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support
    command: touch .post-provisioning-complete
```

and yarn.config

```
  01_node_get:
    cwd: /tmp
    command: 'sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -'

  02_node_install:
    cwd: /tmp
    command: 'sudo yum -y install nodejs'

  03_yarn_get:
    cwd: /tmp
    # don't run the command if yarn is already installed (file /usr/bin/yarn exists)
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
    command: 'sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo'

  04_yarn_install:
    cwd: /tmp
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
    command: 'sudo yum -y install yarn'
```

The logs are quite vague to read however I have noticed I am getting 'upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:' right under /var/log/nginx/error.log

Hoping for some good steering into right direction here. Many thanks in Advance

Comment: I would start by logging into the server via `ssh` and verifying that the Ruby app is running, and you can `curl` it at port `3000`. Then verify you can `curl` nginx at port `80`. Then check the nginx configuration to make sure it is setup to proxy requests to your Rails app on port `3000`

Comment: Also have you checked any EB logs looking for error messages?

Comment: Hi @Marcin I did. below are  the nginx logs


/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2021/03/06 13:01:44 [warn] 3087#0: conflicting server name "_" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2021/03/06 13:19:53 [error] 3091#0: *244 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream